# Spring OAuth2 : tokenInfoUri generates ClassCastException with RFC 7662 endpoint

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring Security OAuth2 with tokenInfoUri pointing to a CXF RFC 7662 endpoint implementation.

When calling the tokenInfoUri, Spring generates a
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Collection

The response from RFC 7662 is :

```
{
   "active":true,
   "client_id":"83EQEL8D1OiCIw",
   "username":"alice",
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "scope":"openid hello.say",
   "iat":1470083268,
   "exp":1470086868
}
```

So, scope is deserialized into a String not a Collection.
Spring doesn't seem to handle this RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662#section-2.2).

Last version of DefaultAccessTokenConverter handle String type but it should split the scope String (space separator) to create a Set for RFC7662 compliance.

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultAccessTokenConverter.java#L154.

Should I create an issue ?

Thanks,
Adrian

Here are the full details ;
Spring Security OAuth 2.0.9.
Stacktrace :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Collection
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultAccessTokenConverter.extractAuthentication(DefaultAccessTokenConverter.java:124) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices.loadAuthentication(RemoteTokenServices.java:115) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager.authenticate(OAuth2AuthenticationManager.java:83) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:150) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
```

Configuration :

```
security:
  user:
    password: user
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: blabli
      clientSecret: blabla
    resource:
      serviceId: ${PREFIX:}resource
      tokenInfoUri: http://localhost:9081/oidc/oauth2/introspect
```

Request :

```
POST /oidc/oauth2/introspect HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, application/*+json
Authorization: Basic ODNFUUVMOEQxT2lDSXc6dy1OZHpERnlJaTJadThQUkRmeE9Xdw==
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_91
Host: localhost:9080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 38
token=faa395452928f5126fc8cf61b66bf0f4
```

Response :

```
{
   "active":true,
   "client_id":"83EQEL8D1OiCIw",
   "username":"alice",
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "scope":"openid hello.say",
   "iat":1470083268,
   "exp":1470086868
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Spring OAuth 2.0.10.